# No text R.string linking possible? String[] names = {};

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listview

Hello I wanted to create a Litsview page with search, image and text with this Tutorial, which works quite well so far.

[Listview Tutorial](https://larntech.net/android-listview-with-searchview-and-onitemclicklistener/)

But is not possible that I can use the texts from the strings.xml?

```
String[] names = {R.string.perkablenkungname,};  // error

String[] names = {getResources().getString(R.string.perkablenkungname),};  ///no error App crash

String[] names = {getString(R.string.perkablenkungname),};   /// no error App crash
```

Sorry for my Bad Englisch!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

create an array inside `string.xml` like this

```
<array name="namesArray">
    <item>Item One</item>
    <item>Item Two</item>
    <item>Item Three</item>
</array>
```

Now access your array like this

```
 String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.namesArray);
```

Comment: The app does not start with this either.
It crashes without an error message

Comment: @whazza83 can you share your code where you are using this?

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.whazza.searchtest;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    String[] perks = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.namesArray);
    String[] name = {"This is apple","This is banana","This is kiwi"};
    String[] lehrbar = {"This is","This is","This is"};
    int[] images = {R.drawable.apple,R.drawable.banana,R.drawable.kiwi};

    List<ItemsModel> itemsModelList = new ArrayList<>();

    ListView listView;

    CustomAdapter customAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);


        for(int i = 0;i < perks.length;i++){

            ItemsModel itemsModel = new ItemsModel(perks[i],name[i],lehrbar[i],images[i]);

            itemsModelList.add(itemsModel);

        }

         customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(itemsModelList,this);

        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu,menu);

        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchView);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                Log.e("Main"," data search"+newText);

                customAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);



                return true;
            }
        });


        return true;

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();


        if(id == R.id.searchView){

            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

        private List<ItemsModel> itemsModelsl;
        private List<ItemsModel> itemsModelListFiltered;
        private Context context;

        public CustomAdapter(List<ItemsModel> itemsModelsl, Context context) {
            this.itemsModelsl = itemsModelsl;
            this.itemsModelListFiltered = itemsModelsl;
            this.context = context;
        }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return itemsModelListFiltered.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return itemsModelListFiltered.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_items,null);


            TextView perks = view.findViewById(R.id.perks);
            TextView name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView lehrbar = view.findViewById(R.id.lehrbar);
            ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.images);

            perks.setText(itemsModelListFiltered.get(position).getPerks());
            name.setText(itemsModelListFiltered.get(position).getName());
            lehrbar.setText(itemsModelListFiltered.get(position).getLehrbar());
            imageView.setImageResource(itemsModelListFiltered.get(position).getImages());

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("main activity","item clicked");
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ItemsPreviewActivity.class).putExtra("items",itemsModelListFiltered.get(position)));

                }
            });

            return view;
        }



        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                        filterResults.count = itemsModelsl.size();
                        filterResults.values = itemsModelsl;

                    }else{
                        List<ItemsModel> resultsModel = new ArrayList<>();
                        String searchStr = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                        for(ItemsModel itemsModel:itemsModelsl){
                            if(itemsModel.getPerks().contains(searchStr) || itemsModel.getName().contains(searchStr)){
                                resultsModel.add(itemsModel);
                               
                            }
                             filterResults.count = resultsModel.size();
                                filterResults.values = resultsModel;
                        }


                    }

                    return filterResults;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                    itemsModelListFiltered = (List<ItemsModel>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            };
            return filter;
        }
    }



}
```